# How to set Active slide in Bootstrap 3 carousel yii2

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, carousel

Hi guys i am confused with one thing

I am assigning more than 3 4 images in `carousel` using `php` loop like below

```
<div class="carousel-inner" id="loop">
    <div class="item">
         <?php foreach ($model->Images as $model2) { ?>
         <div class="item">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="<?= Yii::$app->request->hostInfo?>/upload/<?=$model2->image?>" alt="">
         </div>
         <?php }  ?>          
</div>
```

It doesnt images separately because i havent assigned any slide as active and i could not find out how to set the first slide or any of those slide class to `active` via javascript or any other way

What should i use here? `Javascript` or any other property of `carousel`?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the first image or item as active like

```
    <?php $counter=0; foreach ($model->Images as $model2) { $counter++; ?>
     <div class="item <?= ($counter==1)?'active':'' ?> ">
          <img class="img-responsive <?= ($counter==1)?'active':'' ?> " src="<?= Yii::$app->request->hostInfo?>/upload/<?=$model2->image?>" alt="">
     </div>
     <?php }  ?>
```